# Set HTTP GET Parameters in Finagle

Tags: finagle

In Finagle, how do I create a request an HTTP GET request with parameters in a safe, clean way?

```
val request = RequestBuilder()
  .url("http://www.example.com/test")
  .addParameter("key", "value")   // this doesn't exist
  .buildGet()
request    // should be a GET request for http://www.example.com/test?key=value
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the confusingly-named `Request.queryString`:

```
val request = RequestBuilder()
  .url(Request.queryString("http://www.example.com/test", Map("key" -> "value"))
  .buildGet()
```

Answer (score 2):

The arguments passed to `RequestBuilder.url()` are expected to be fully-formed, so Finagle doesn't provide any way to tack on more query parameters.

One way to solve this would be to construct a URL object outside of the context of the `RequestBuilder` chain. You could define your query parameters in a `Map`, turn it into a query string, and then concatenate it to the base URL:

```
val paramStr = Map("key" -> "value", ...) map { case (k, v) =>
  k + '=' + v
} mkString("?", "&", "")

val request = RequestBuilder.safeBuildGet(
  RequestBuilder.create()
    .url("http://www.example.com/test" + paramsStr)
)
```

Note that you'll need to encode any query parameters that you specify in the `Map`.

Comment: This solution doesn't escape special characters though, right?

Answer (score -1):

You can safely create your request by this way:

```
import java.net.URL
import com.twitter.finagle.http.{Http, RequestBuilder}

val request = RequestBuilder()
             .url(new URL("http://www.example.com/test?key=value"))
             .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json") //if you need
             .buildGet()
```